# Is there a way to control a Java program's file read/write/run permissions?

Tags: java, javascript

In theory it shouldn't be difficult to write a perfectly isolated sandbox. Unfortunately, people want features like file read/write access and Runtime.exec(), which then require a complicated (and often flawed) set of restrictions to maintain security.

Does anyone know a way to tell Java (or JavaScript) to require permission from a pop up window before allowing a program to perform any of these (or other) potentially insecure actions?

Comment: When you are talking about javascript, are you talking about rhino (JS on Java)? In that case, this is actually an interesting question.

Comment: I didn't realize that there was an open source Java based JS engine. Unfortunately, I don't code in Java very often so this approach would be a huge time sink.